# Stored procedure for importing data from a server to another server

Tags: sql-server

This is an example of a table that has the following columns:

```
Fault_Count|Status|Date_Received|Fin_Week
1          |Open  |2017/03/11  |  49
1          |Closed|2017/03/17  |  50
```

I am trying to retrieve faults that were reported in a specific financial week (FinWeek). The problem arise when I use the Date and Status to filter.

I want to retrieve faults that were open in a specific week even though their status now is closed. Can you help me figure out the SQL query that can get the dates for any last Saturday and count back 7 days of the same week?

Please assist

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Are these the only columns we have to work with?  Is there a reason we want to look back seven days if we already have financial week?